# Lack of understanding crash report

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have this crash report.

```
Incident Identifier: CA9E350A-C842-4349-AAD8-E9E62E93BDD1
CrashReporter Key:   360bc129d2f79a48e291eb5ca38b24e822ed5b6b
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:         OrientalDailyiOS [1502]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/39480A57-68FF-4C46-8445-340EFE204119/OrientalDailyiOS.app/OrientalDailyiOS
Identifier:      OrientalDailyiOS
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-10-14 15:49:10.884 -0700
OS Version:      iOS 6.0 (10A403)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x37a0a29e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34e3197a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x37955b70 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 160
3   OrientalDailyiOS                0x00064fdc -[Main_NewsDetail viewDidLoad] (Main_NewsDetail.m:43)
4   UIKit                           0x386cb590 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 360
5   UIKit                           0x38757336 -[UIViewController shouldAutorotate] + 22
6   UIKit                           0x38798cd4 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] + 1540
7   UIKit                           0x38797fca -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 3390
8   UIKit                           0x388ba252 -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:] + 26
9   Foundation                      0x34364a6a __NSFireDelayedPerform + 446
10  CoreFoundation                  0x379df5da __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 10
11  CoreFoundation                  0x379df28c __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 268
12  CoreFoundation                  0x379ddefc __CFRunLoopRun + 1228
13  CoreFoundation                  0x37950eb8 0x37948000 + 36536
14  CoreFoundation                  0x37950d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
15  GraphicsServices                0x373e32e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
16  UIKit                           0x387002fc 0x386a9000 + 357116
17  OrientalDailyiOS                0x0005fac2 main (main.m:16)
18  OrientalDailyiOS                0x0005fa84 0x5e000 + 6788
```

However, I couldn't know where is error, I play around with my apps but show no error.

I also tried iOS 6 with iPad, no problem.

what apple feedback was

```
We found that your app crashed on iPad running iOS 6, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Your app crashed on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks when we:

1. Launch the app.
2. Tap any item on main page.
3. App crashes.
```

**Update**

```
Main_NewDetails

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[slider setHidden:YES];
DatabaseAction *getnews = [[[DatabaseAction alloc] init] autorelease];
self.singlenews = [getnews retrieveSingleNews:newsid];
self.defaultsize = [getnews retrieveFont];
font = [self.defaultsize objectAtIndex:0];
currentsize = font.Font_Size;
News *new = [self.singlenews objectAtIndex:0];
if(self.catsid != 10)
    self.header.text = new.News_Cat_Name;
else
    self.header.text = @"評論";
self.title.text = new.News_Title;
authortext = new.News_Author;
self.content.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", new.News_IntroText,  new.News_FullText];
self.introtext = new.News_IntroText;
self.content.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:currentsize];
self.date.text = new.News_ArticalDate;
self.commentno.text = @"留言: 0";
imagepath = new.News_ImagePath;
onetime = YES;

if([Constant_Config NetworkStatus]){
    if(![imagepath isEqualToString:@"no picture"]){
        NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
        NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                                            initWithTarget:self
                                            selector:@selector(loadImage)
                                            object:nil];
        [queue addOperation:operation];
        [operation release];
    }

    NetworkHandler *networkHandler=[[NetworkHandler alloc] init];
    GetTotalCommentsRequest *gettotalcomments= [[GetTotalCommentsRequest alloc] init:newsid];

    [networkHandler setDelegate:self];
    [networkHandler request:gettotalcomments];
    [gettotalcomments release];
    [networkHandler release];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:[self addbanner]];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:[self addbanner]];
}

[self setlabelXY];

AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO];
}
```

Comment: See my answer below. Posting the code of your viewDidLoad method might help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking at is a stack trace, the path the program goes through your code. Each line is a function, starting at the main run loop (18) and ending at the crash (0).

The most useful parts are the functions that you have created in your app `OrientalDailyiOS` at frame 3.

Your app is crashing trying to access an object in an NSArray (frame 2) inside your `Main_NewsDetail viewDidLoad]` method (frame 3).

**Edit**

As I said, your app is crashing trying to access an object in an NSArray. Take a closer look at your application specifically the two lines in your `viewDidLoad` method that use the method that's crashing above `objectAtIndex:`.

```
font = [self.defaultsize objectAtIndex:0];

News *new = [self.singlenews objectAtIndex:0];
```

How are you populating `self.singlenews` ? What is the case were it could have no objects?

Comment: However, I run through this xib, there is no problem occure, i don't know why they still got happen

Comment: When i generate an ipa file and sync into devices, it got error but when i direct debug from xcode, it got no problem, what is the problem?